# Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "pod.yaml":

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am getting the following error when I run

```
kubectl create -f pod.yaml
```

error

```
Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "pod.yaml": Pod in 
version "applicant:v1" cannot be handled as a Pod: no kind "Pod" is 
registered for version "applicant:v1"
```

minikube is up and running and I even tried to change it to `kind: Deployment` but I got another error saying:

```
error: unable to recognize "pod.yaml": no matches for /, Kind=Deployment
```

yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: customer-applicant
  labels:
    app: applicant-vue
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: applicant-vue
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: applicant-vue 
    spec:
      containers: 
      - name: api-applicant
        image: api-applicant
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
          - containerPort: 8000
        resources: {}
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /usr/local/tomcat/logs
            name: api-applicant-claim 

# import       
      - name: applicant-import
        image: applicant-import
        resources: {}

# cache
      - name: cache
        image: cache
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "536870912"

# storage
      - name: storage
        image: storage
        ports:
         - containerPort: 7000
         - containerPort: 7001
         - containerPort: 7199
         - containerPort: 9042
         - containerPort: 9160
        resources: {}
# view
      - name: view
        image: view
        ports:
         - containerPort: 3000
        resources: {}

      volumes:
        - name: applicant-claim
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: applicant-claim
 # tomcat
      - name: tomcat
        image: tomcat
# node
      - name: node
        image: node
        resources: {}
# openJdk
      - name: node
      - image: node
        resources: {}
```

Comment: Please post your `pod.yaml`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a lot of issues here. I've described some of them:

**1.** 
`pod.yaml` file's structure is a structure of a `Deployment` object.

**2.**
`apiVersion` for `Deployment` depends of kubernetes version:

- `apps/v1beta1` for versions before 1.8.0
- `apps/v1beta2` for versions starting from 1.8.0 before 1.9.0
- `apps/v1` for versions starting from 1.9.0

So, if you deploy your `pod.yaml` on the latest kubernetes cluster it should be started from:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
```

**3.**
The part:

```
spec:
  replicas: 1
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Mi
  template:
    metadata:
      labels: 
        app: product-ratings-vue
```

should be changed to:

```
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels: 
        app: product-ratings-vue
```

**4.**
Second `spec` block should be moved on the same level as `spec.template.metadata`:

```
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      template:
        metadata:
          labels: 
            app: product-ratings-vue
        spec:
          containers:
```

The final `deployment.yaml` is:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: customer-ratings
  labels:
    app: product-ratings-vue
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: product-ratings-vue
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: product-ratings-vue 
    spec:
      containers: 
      - name: api-service
        image: api-service
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
          - containerPort: 8000
        resources: {}
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /usr/local/tomcat/logs
            name: api-service-claim 

# ekomi-import       
      - name: ekomi-import
        image: ekomi-import
        resources: {}

# cache
      - name: cache
        image: cache
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "536870912"

# storage
      - name: storage
        image: storage
        ports:
         - containerPort: 7000
         - containerPort: 7001
         - containerPort: 7199
         - containerPort: 9042
         - containerPort: 9160
        resources: {}
# view
      - name: view
        image: view
        ports:
         - containerPort: 3000
        resources: {}

 # tomcat
      - name: tomcat
        image: tomcat
# node
      - name: node
        image: node
        resources: {}
# openJdk
      - name: node
        image: node
        resources: {}

      volumes:
        - name: api-service-claim
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: api-service-claim
```

Comment: chat? I will mark it as solved because it does resolve the issue of the question.

Comment: @Drew1208 let's a chat

Comment: `volumes` statement should be below all items from `containers`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165267/discussion-between-drew1208-and-nickolay).